# Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 1 SSD upgrade issue

Tags: windows, laptop, ssd, thinkpad

I am attempting to add a new SSD to a Lenovo Carbon X1 Gen1 laptop and I am having issues with my Windows 10 bootable media (USB) detecting the SSD that I am attempting to use on this device.

I purchased a Toptekits M.2 NGFF SSD to 26 pin adapter that is specifically made for the Carbon X1 Gen1. After reading reviews it appears that it works and no one is having any issues with this little piece of hardware. I then purchased a "recommended" Toshiba 256GB NVMe SSD (KBG30ZMS256G). No luck. The bootable media was not able to find a storage device to install Windows 10 on. I then searched the internet for the drivers for this device and installed all of them during the attempt to discover a device with the Windows 10 media. Still no luck.

At this point, I am about to just go and spend the money on the original SSD for this device even though it is less storage for a higher price. Am I missing something? Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure your first generation X1 ThinkPad has an NVMe socket for it. I could not find this on the support website. My fourth generation X1 does have an NVMe socket and I have a 1 TB Samsung NVMe drive in it

Comment: It does not have a direct socket, however, I did purchase an adapter that supposedly made to make the NVMe SSD work.

Comment: Possibly try updating the X1 BIOS with a bootable USB update key from the Lenovo Support site

Comment: After downloading a few of the Bootable ISOs and attempting to create a medium to update the BIOS - It does not appear to be possible. I can not get any of them to boot via USB in both UEFI and Legacy.

Comment: Can you get into BIOS?  Try turning off Secure Boot, restart and try BIOS updates again

Comment: NVMe SSDs often with not work with PCs designed for SATA SSDs.

Comment: Secure Boot has been turned off since my first attempt. I was basically going off a few year old forum post where individuals had success with getting this specific SSD to work with this laptop. I may just have to bite the bullet and buy the original SSD designed for the system - I can't find much more about other SSDs that are compatible.

Comment: It may be best now to get the SSD from Lenovo as you know that will work

Comment: At this point that's what i'm thinking too. I've been messing around with this for almost a week and luckily have only dropped a small amount of money on it as the laptop itself was given to me and I was hoping to fire it up as a machine to just test software and mess around with. The small storage space for price that even used SSDs on eBay that are meant for this laptop turn me off. I think about $60USD is the standard price for just 180gb. Thanks for the help!

Comment: At this point, if I post replacement as an answer are you happy to accept it?

Comment: That would be completely acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your first generation X1 ThinkPad has an NVMe socket for it. I could not find this on the support website. If, after trying the NVMe option, you find it is not compatible with the first generation X1, then get a regular SSD drive from Lenovo Support

Answer (score 0):

x1 carbon 1st gen must be NGFF. NVMe will not work.